# understanding command execution in shell implementation

Tags: c, exec, posix, system-calls, ansi-c

I am trying to understand a program [here](https://github.com/kalpishs/Unix-Shell-Implementation-in-C/blob/master/shell.c) 
I have not been able to  understand the 
`static int split(char *cmd_exec, int input, int first, int last)` function  what is the purpose of int input,int first,int last here ,
this function returns `return command(input, first, last, new_cmd_exec1);` 
what does input,first,last and new_cmd_exec1 signify here?
Why do we need to spilt the commands passed on to a shell ?
The relevant code is following

```
static int split(char *cmd_exec, int input, int first, int last)
{
    char *new_cmd_exec1;  
    new_cmd_exec1=strdup(cmd_exec);
   //else
      {
        int m=1;
        args[0]=strtok(cmd_exec," ");       
        while((args[m]=strtok(NULL," "))!=NULL)
              m++;
        args[m]=NULL;
        if (args[0] != NULL) 
            {

            if (strcmp(args[0], "exit") == 0) 
                    exit(0);
            if (strcmp(args[0], "echo") != 0) 
                    {
                      cmd_exec = skipcomma(new_cmd_exec1);
                      int m=1;
                      args[0]=strtok(cmd_exec," ");       
                      while((args[m]=strtok(NULL," "))!=NULL)
                                m++;
                      args[m]=NULL;

                    }
            if(strcmp("cd",args[0])==0)
                    {
                    change_directory();
                    return 1;
                    }
            else if(strcmp("pwd",args[0])==0)
                    {
                    parent_directory();
                    return 1;
                    }

            }
        }
    return command(input, first, last, new_cmd_exec1);
}
```

Comment: 1) Post the relevant code here and don't make us click links. 2) What don't you understand? The syntax? The logic?

Comment: The logic part.

Answer (score 0):

The meaning of the variables isn't clear from the code you posted. However, if you can find any documentation for, or the definition of, the function `command()`, you may be able to learn their intended purpose.

Having said that, it's pretty clear from the code that these parameters are just copies of the parameters that were initially passed to `split()` and passed on to `command()`, so it is likely that the integers are general purpose parameters whose meaning will depend on the eventual type of command executed.